# SQL Server split a single column multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a database table that has a column with stacked data with two levels with a column that I want to break a part. Here is the example of the data (data changed to protect the innocent :) :

#### Table

```
ID = varchar(100)
CarData = varchar(1000)

ID       CarData
1        Nissan:blue:20000,Ford:green:10000
2        Nissan:steel:20001,Ford:blue:10001,Chevy:blue:10000,Ford:olive:10000
** Note that cardata can is not fixed, and can have many cars in it
```

#### Output Desired:

```
ID   Manufacture    Color     Cost
1    Nissan         Blue      20000
1    Ford           green     10000
2    Nissan         steel      20001
... and on
```

So to say it plainly I need to break the first stacked field which is a comma and create a row for that, then break the second stacked field which is a colon into columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible for you to correct this terrible terrible database design?

Comment: @JNK: Here's to hoping the answer to his question is part of that greater effort.

Comment: If you need to run this frequently, you might be better served by creating a CLR function and leverage the existing string library (faster, better, etc) http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/26/faster-more-scalable-sqlclr-string-splitting.aspx

Comment: A note here that what you are proposing can possibly create identical records.  It's possible for an entity to own two blue ford's that both cost 20000.  You need an additional column, either an ordinal or a another ID.

Comment: @bilinkc - If he needs to run this frequently, he ***really*** needs to redesign the table, or at very least turn it into an indexed view. I think most of us are hoping this is part of a table redesign.

Comment: And for the OP - it's really to understate how horrible this table design is. I know you can't always just make a unilateral change to fix this kind of thing, but working to make that happens needs to be your primary mission here.

Answer (score 6):

```
-- Sample data
declare @T table(ID int, CarData varchar(100))
insert into @T values 
(1,        'Nissan:blue:20000,Ford:green:10000'),
(2,        'Nissan:steel:20001,Ford:blue:10001,Chevy:blue:10000,Ford:olive:10000')

-- Recursice CTE to get one row for each car
;with cte(ID, Car, CarData) as
(
  select ID,
         cast(substring(CarData+',', 1, charindex(',', CarData+',')-1) as varchar(100)),
         stuff(CarData, 1, charindex(',', CarData), '')+','
  from @T
  where len(CarData) > 0
  union all
  select ID,
         cast(substring(CarData, 1, charindex(',', CarData)-1) as varchar(100)),
         stuff(CarData, 1, charindex(',', CarData), '')
  from cte
  where len(CarData) > 0
)
-- Use parsename to split the car data
select ID,
       parsename(replace(Car, ':', '.'), 3) as Manufacture,
       parsename(replace(Car, ':', '.'), 2) as Color,
       parsename(replace(Car, ':', '.'), 1) as Cost
from cte
order by ID
```

Result:

```
ID  Manufacture  Color   Cost
--  -----------  ------   -----
1   Nissan       blue    20000
1   Ford         green   10000
2   Nissan       steel   20001
2   Ford         blue    10001
2   Chevy        blue    10000
2   Ford         olive   10000
```

**Edit 1**

You will have trouble with `parsename` if  color, cost or a manufacturer name contains a `.`. If that is the case you should try this instead.

```
-- Sample data
declare @T table(ID int, CarData varchar(100))
insert into @T values 
(1,        'Nissan:blue:20000,Ford:green:10000'),
(2,        'Nissan:steel:20001,Ford:blue:10001,Chevy:blue:10000,Ford:olive:10000')

-- Recursice CTE to get one row for each car
;with cte(ID, Car, CarData) as
(
  select ID,
         cast(substring(CarData+',', 1, charindex(',', CarData+',')-1) as varchar(100)),
         stuff(CarData, 1, charindex(',', CarData), '')+','
  from @T
  where len(CarData) > 0
  union all
  select ID,
         cast(substring(CarData, 1, charindex(',', CarData)-1) as varchar(100)),
         stuff(CarData, 1, charindex(',', CarData), '')
  from cte
  where len(CarData) > 0
)
-- Split the car data with substring
select ID,
       substring(Car, 1, P1.Pos-1) as Manufacture,
       substring(Car, P1.Pos+1, P2.Pos-P1.Pos-1) as Color,
       substring(Car, P2.Pos+1, len(Car)-P2.Pos) as Cost
from cte
  cross apply (select charindex(':', Car)) as P1(Pos)
  cross apply (select charindex(':', Car, P1.Pos+1)) as P2(Pos)
order by ID
```

Comment: Awesome. Beat me to it by seconds.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I will start too look at this in the next hour, appreciate all the help so quickly... I know the DB design is crap, the team I am on does not understand DB design...

Comment: OK, I have 90% of the query working with my real data, however, I get in the outer query the Car = combined field parsed away from comma delimited. But I am not getting any data out of the parsename(replace(Car, ':', '.'), 1) as Cost. Now yours works perfect, I am just wondering if you could explain a little more about what the parsename is doing and what the '.' is representing?

Comment: WOW! I never used **'PARSENAME'** because of the limitations of the **'sysname'** , but in this case works amazingly fast.  +1 because I can't do +1000 :)

Comment: @Michael - You can read about `parsename` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx. The function is used to separate four part names `Server.DataBase.Owner.Table`. It will not work if you have more than four words. The separator is `.` so you need to first replace all `:` with `.`.

Comment: I just figured that out, which is why my query is failing... I truly do appreciate the help.

Comment: @Michael - I have updated the answer for the case when you have `.` as a part of the data.

Comment: So I have say 6 fields in the colon delimited section, so I have been messing with SUBSTRING and FINDSTRING, but in 2005 FINDSTRING does not seem to be recongnized, any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Michael - You can just continue to add the `cross apply`, one for each `:` and then use that in the substring statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this string splitting function](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) to produce a table of results.

I would first call `dbo.split()` using a `,` as the separator character. Then you'll have a list of items like:

```
Nissan:blue:20000
Ford:green:10000
Nissan:steel:20001
Ford:blue:10001
Chevy:blue:10000
Ford:olive:10000
```

From there you can call `dbo.split()` again using `:` as your separator. Each call will result in exactly three records (assuming your design as at least that "normal").

As @JNK mentioned in his comment, hopefully this is not something you'd want to be running regularly.

**EDIT:**

Some sample code to get you started:

```
SELECT *
INTO #YuckyCar
FROM (
  SELECT 1 ID, 'Nissan:blue:20000,Ford:green:10000' CarData
  UNION
  SELECT 2, 'Nissan:steel:20001,Ford:blue:10001,Chevy:blue:10000,Ford:olive:10000'
) T;

-- Shows logical step #1
SELECT ID, X.items MoreCarData
FROM #YuckyCar CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(CarData, ',') X;

-- Shows logical step #2
SELECT Q.ID, Y.items
FROM (
  SELECT ID, X.items MoreCarData
  FROM #YuckyCar CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(CarData, ',') X) Q CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Q.MoreCarData, ':') Y

DROP TABLE #YuckyCar;
```

The problem in the last part is that you can't guarantee row 1 = Manufacturer, row 2 = Color, row 3 = Cost.

Comment: Yes, I would have to run this query many times a day, its a small group DB.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

**[EDIT]** Your ID is a varchar(100) and you do not specify if it is a primary key, so I made some changes ... ID does't have to be primary key in this case.

```
declare @T table(ID varchar(100), CarData varchar(1000))
declare @OUT table(pk INT IDENTITY(1,1), ID varchar(100), Manufacture varchar(100), Color VARCHAR(100), Cost INT)
insert into @T (ID, CarData) values 
('1', 'Nissan:blue:20000,Ford:green:10000'),
('2', 'Nissan:steel:20001,Ford:blue:10001,Chevy:blue:10000,Ford:olive:10000')

DECLARE @x XML, @i INT, @ID VARCHAR(100), @maxi INT; 
;WITH list AS (SELECT pk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), * FROM @T)
  SELECT @i=1, @maxi=MAX(pk) FROM list;
WHILE @i <= @maxi
BEGIN
  ;WITH list AS (SELECT pk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), * FROM @T)
    SELECT
       @x = CAST( '<root><car><prop>' + 
                  REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                       CarData
                      ,':'
                      ,'</prop><prop>'
                    )
                    ,','
                    ,'</prop></car><car><prop>'
                  ) + 
                  '</prop></car></root>'
             AS XML)
     , @ID = ID 
    FROM list 
    WHERE pk = @i

  INSERT INTO @OUT 
    SELECT 
       ID = @ID
      ,Manufacture = x.value('./prop[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
      ,Color   = x.value('./prop[2]','VARCHAR(100)')
      ,Cost    = x.value('./prop[3]','INT')
    FROM @x.nodes('/root/car') AS T(x)

  SET @i = @i + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM @OUT

/* -- OUTPUT
ID  Manufacture   Color   Cost
--------------------------------
1   Nissan        blue    20000
1   Ford          green   10000
2   Nissan        steel   20001
2   Ford          blue    10001
2   Chevy         blue    10000
2   Ford          olive   10000
*/
```

Comment: @EricZ: Thanks, but my solution looks like a bad joke if you run it against 25000 records (I tried testing it and 1 second for Mikael's solution is way faster than minutes for mine).